# Convert a nested dict to a dict that only include list items that has a unique set of keys

Tags: python, json, yaml

How do I convert the following nested dict to a dict that only include list items that has a unique set of keys (regardless of the values)?

I don't know how many levels of nesting there are, and I don't care which list item that is returned, as long as it has an unique set of keys (for the list that the item is part of)

(I am trying to generate an example file from a very long YAML file for documentation purposes)

```
input = { 
   "mylist": [
      {
         "key1": "1333", 
         "key2": [
                  { 
                   "key2a":134,
                   "key2b":1373
                    },
                  { 
                   "key2a":124,
                   "key2b":136
                    }
                  ]
      },{
         "key1": "875", 
         "key2": [
                  { 
                   "key2a":999,
                   "key2b":6567
                    },
                  { 
                   "key2a":8765,
                   "key2b":875
                    }
                  ]
      },{
         "key1": "6754", 
         "key3": 3232
      },{
         "key1": "34545", 
         "key3": 34554
      }
   ]
 }
```

needed output:

```
{ 
   "mylist": [
      {
         "key1": "1333", 
         "key2": [
                  { "key2a":134,
                   "key2b":1373
                    }
                  ]
      },{
         "key1": "6754", 
         "key3": 3232
      }
   ]
}
```

I made this (verbose) code that solves it by fetching and storing all keys it finds in list item objects, but I am sure this can be done in a shorter way?

```
input = collections.OrderedDict(input)
def get_keys(obj,keys=[]):
    if isinstance(obj, (dict,collections.OrderedDict)):
        for k, v in obj.items():
            if not isinstance(v, (dict,collections.OrderedDict)):
                keys.append(k)        
            get_keys(v,keys)
    elif isinstance(obj, list):
        for elem in obj:
            if not isinstance(elem, (dict,collections.OrderedDict,list)):
                keys.append(elem)
            get_keys(elem,keys)
    return keys

def traverse(obj,  callback=None):
    if isinstance(obj, (dict,collections.OrderedDict)):        
        value = {k: traverse(v, callback)
                 for k, v in obj.items()}
    elif isinstance(obj, list):
        value = [traverse(elem,  callback)
                 for elem in obj]
    else:
        value = obj
    if callback is None:
        return value
    else:
        return callback(value)

def traverse_modify(obj):
    def yaml_shortener(obj):
        duplicates = []
        if isinstance(obj,list) and len(obj)>1:
            return_list = []
            for i,elem in enumerate(obj):
                if not any(Counter(get_keys(elem,keys=[])) == Counter(item) for item in duplicates): 
                    return_list.append(elem)
                    duplicates.append(get_keys(elem,keys=[]))       
            return return_list
        else:
            return obj
    return traverse(obj, callback=yaml_shortener)   

def shorten_yaml(obj):
    return traverse_modify(obj)

print json.dumps(shorten_yaml(input),indent=3)
```

Comment: What are the selection conditions? For example, why `"key2a":999` was rejected whereas `"key2a":134` was recorded?

Comment: hand-edited json :)  The values does not matter. If a list has many items with the same key-structure, remove all but one. Hope it make sense.

Comment: So in essence, it's a random selection of 1 key only. In other words, if there are 4 instances of 'key2a', just save one of them only, and disregard the rest. Is that correct?

Comment: I think the point is that the structural integrity of the items in the list must be kept, i cannot remove keys from the individual dict-items in the list. But sure, if there is two (or more)  items in a list that consist of a  'key2a', [{'key2a':1},{'key2a:2}] then all items but one can be removed

Comment: Why is `"key1": "875"`? missing?

Comment: 'key1':875 is part of a list item that is considered a duplicate. The first "root" list  has 4 "dict" objects inside it. the first two has the same set of keys (and also nr 3 and 4), so one of each is removed in the output. but then the remaining dict also has lists in them, and duplicate items are removed from this sub-list as well in the same way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I assume that the value associated to a dictionary key is either a
list of dictionaries or a *scalar* value. This value is processed by function
convert_value(), which:

- calls function process_dict_list() to extract the unique set of keys in case the value is a list of dictionaries;
- leaves the value unchanged if it is a *scalar*.

The *magic* happens inside function convert_dict_list(), which:

- collects all the keys (and values) of each dictionary of the passed list of dictionaries;
- sorts them and creates a temporary dictionary mapping each tuple of keys into the corresponding list of converted values; such a dictionary contains - of course - unique tuple of keys, exactly as required;
- finally the tuples of keys and list of values are converted back into expected dictionaries.

Function convert() is a simple interface function accepting a dictionary with the input data: it simply converts the dictionary into a list of dictionaries (with a single item) and calls the previous function to process it.

Below is the full code:

```
def convert(a_dict):
    return convert_dict_list([a_dict])[0]

def convert_dict_list(dict_list):
    sorted_items = (zip(*sorted(d.iteritems())) for d in dict_list)
    tmp_dict = dict((tuple(keys), map(convert_value, values))
        for (keys, values) in sorted_items)
    return map(dict, [zip(k, v) for (k, v) in tmp_dict.iteritems()])

def convert_value(val):
    return convert_dict_list(val) if isinstance(val, list) else val
```

And here is the output generated by using the example input:

```
>>> print convert(input)
{'mylist': [{'key3': 34554, 'key1': '34545'}, {'key2': [{'key2b': 875, 'key2a': 8765}], 'key1': '875'}]}
```

Comment: it even works if keys has dict as a value, as if i add ,{"key4": { "key5":23}},{"key4": { "key5":44}} it will remove one of "key4" correctly.